# Scanner / printer firewall

Tags: printing, firewall, scanner

My firewall is blocking the scanner from working but the printer works fine. Obviously when i turn off the firewall they both work. I can't figure out how to configure the firewall to allow the scanner.[image]

the address is 192.168.0.5:515

I am quite a novice although I am an expert at the basics of ubuntu, just unfamiliar with port and IP stuff..

Answer (score 2):

Yes, to configure ubuntu firewall for scanner, it is easy just use terminal:
type in (after entering your password):

```
sudo ufw allow from xxx.xxx.x.xxx
```

(your printer's URL), then press "Enter"
That's it. Good luck.